# maven dependency not resolved, not authorized error

Tags: eclipse, maven, dkpro-core

I am trying to use a maven project in eclipse. This is the first time I am using maven repository.
I am using maven 3.2.3
When I do

```
mvn clean install -U
```

it shows these errors

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building TreetaggerV2 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://hlt-services4.fbk.eu:8080/artifactory/repo/de/tudarmstadt/ukp/dkpro/core/de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.treetagger-bin/20131118.0/de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.treetagger-bin-20131118.0.pom
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/de/tudarmstadt/ukp/dkpro/core/de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.treetagger-bin/20131118.0/de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.treetagger-bin-20131118.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.016 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-11-11T01:28:05-08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/333M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project TreetaggerV2: Could not resolve dependencies for project eu.excitementproject:TreetaggerV2:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core:de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.treetagger-bin:jar:20131118.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core:de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.treetagger-bin:jar:20131118.0: Could not transfer artifact de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core:de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.treetagger-bin:pom:20131118.0 from/to FBK (http://hlt-services4.fbk.eu:8080/artifactory/repo): Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

my pom file is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>eu.excitementproject</groupId>
  <artifactId>TreetaggerV2</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>eu.excitementproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.4</version>
  </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>eu.excitementproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>lap</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.4</version>
  </dependency> 


  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- TreeTagger related dependencies -->
      <dependency>
              <groupId>de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core</groupId>
              <artifactId>de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.treetagger-bin</artifactId>
              <version>20131118.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
              <groupId>de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core</groupId>
              <artifactId>de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.treetagger-model-de</artifactId>
              <version>20121207.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
              <groupId>de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core</groupId>
              <artifactId>de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.treetagger-model-en</artifactId>
              <version>20111109.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
              <groupId>de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core</groupId>
              <artifactId>de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.treetagger-model-it</artifactId>
              <version>20101115.0</version>
      </dependency>
<!-- end of TreeTagger related dependencies -->


</dependencies>

<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>FBK</id>
    <url>http://hlt-services4.fbk.eu:8080/artifactory/repo</url>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
  </repository>
</repositories>

</project>
```

I want to add treetagger from dkpro to the pom , but it gives an error?

Comment: have you given setting.xml files path? and do you have proper repository at that particular location?

Comment: I am new to maven and I can see these jar files in my maven repository. The following command shows these jar files                                                                    ls ~/.m2/repository/de/tudarmstadt/ukp/dkpro/core/de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.treetagger-bin/
20130228.0 20131118.0 , but I am not sure what settings do I need to give in settings.xml and where do i find it?

Comment: even you havent given packaging type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are trying to use Excitement. They have some documentation to help you get TreeTagger set up: https://github.com/hltfbk/Excitement-Open-Platform/wiki/Step-by-Step,-TreeTagger-Installation

Unfortunately, the TreeTagger license does not permit redistribution of the binaries (or models), that is why you have to package the models and binaries yourself for use with Excitement (or DKPr Core for that matter).

*Disclosure: I'm a developer of DKPro Core.*

That said, the articles mentioned my MariuszS are also in general great pointers.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I got the correct document from Excitement and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Read this articles:

- [TreeTagger configuration with DKPro and Maven](http://blog.roland-kluge.de/?p=552)
- [How to package resources (e.g. models) as Maven Artifacts](https://code.google.com/p/dkpro-core-asl/wiki/PackagingResources)

There is problem with accessing file: [**de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.treetagger-bin-20131118.0.pom**](http://hlt-services4.fbk.eu:8080/artifactory/repo/de/tudarmstadt/ukp/dkpro/core/de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.treetagger-bin/20131118.0/de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.treetagger-bin-20131118.0.pom)

> **HTTP Status 401** - Download request for repo:path 'tl-repository:de/tudarmstadt/ukp/dkpro/core/de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.treetagger-bin/20131118.0/de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.treetagger-bin-20131118.0.pom' is **forbidden for user 'anonymous'**.

In general you need to add `server` definition with creditensial to `settings.xml`.

```
<settings>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>hlt-services4.fbk.eu</id>
      <username>user</username>
      <password>password</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

but in your particular case you need to install this jars locally using ant script (link above)

> (..) we offer Ant scripts to automatically download the resources and package them as DKPro-compatible JARs. When the license permits, we upload these to our public Maven repository.

You can try building your project in offline mode `-O` if all artifacts are installed locally.

More: [Adding Credentials to Your Maven Settings](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/_adding_credentials_to_your_maven_settings.html)

Comment: but I do not have any settings.xml in my .m2/repository and where can I find user and passwords for dkpro

Comment: I had installed the jars locally using the ant script. Hence the ls command shows these jars, but still I am not able to understand why it does not find them when they are present in .m2/repository.